# How to correct showing buttons in list of elements with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have page with some lists of elements. I want to show "copy" button near every elements if the mouse is over an element.
I think about some variants:
1) Add button to all elements, hide it and show when mouse is over (element:hover)
2) Add listeners to every elements, and create button when mouse is over
3) Create custom structural directive for it

There are many elements on one page(~3000), and I want to use the most optimal method. Can anybody help?

Comment: I would use the way you find the easiest, and see if it causes any performance problem. If it doesn't you're done. If it does, then start worrying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add hidden button to all elements, and show when mouse is over - it work bad.
Then, I tried to add button in html when mouse is over, and it work bad too.
True way:
generate list with elements after scrolling, add hidden button to generated elements and add search field to searching data in list.
See this questions [How to get filtered data after *ngFor from component with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175294/how-to-get-filtered-data-after-ngfor-from-component-with-angular2/51175387)

See [How can I speed up ngFor for a large array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600154/how-can-i-speed-up-ngfor-for-a-large-array) for create generator