# How to get filtered data after *ngFor from component with Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to get filtered list of data in my component. 
In view i have something like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf=”(items | filter:search.value) as result”>
  <div *ngFor=”let item of result”>
    {{item}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And I need to get `result` from component. 
Yes, I can add `{{result_setter(result)}}` to ng-container, and create method with variable in component:

```js
filtered_data;

result_setter(data) {
  this.filtered_data = data;
}
```

But it's look like shit. Can anybody help?
I found this article https://netbasal.com/using-pipe-results-in-angular-templates-430683fa2213, and users in comments has this problem too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes are made for displaying data only.

If you want to filter your values and get them in your component, consider filtering them on query change.

```
<input type="file" [(ngModel)]="search" (input)="filterData">

filterData() {
  this.filteredData = this.data.filter(item => /* your filtering */);
}
```

**EDIT** You can also use an instance of your pipe to filter your data like so

```
filterData() {
  const pipe = new FilterPipe(); // Consider moving this as a class member
  this.filteredData = pipe.transform(this.data, this.search);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean, using pipes like filter for lists is bad idea?

Comment: I mean using pipes for filtering data **and showing it to your user** is a good idea, but using a pipe for filtering data **and using in your component's TS** is a bad idea.

Comment: But what if I want to delete, or change all filtered data?

Comment: Then as I said, you bind to your `input` event on your search input, and filter your data manually.

Comment: Ok, if need to show filtered data - use pipe. If need to work with this data in future - use methods in component. Thank you

Comment: Exactly, and no problem !

Comment: By the way, if you have already made the pipe, you can simply create an instance of it to filter instead of using `data.filter`. I edited my answer to show you that, @Flamine

Comment: Ok, I will do by this way, Thank you