# Comparing two large objects in angular makes rendering slow

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have two observables fetched from RTDB. One is questions (500 items) and other is answers (2000 items).

I am using nested *ngFor  to compare and  display question and respective answers. It works fine , but it renders slowly and make the whole application lag.

```
 <ion-slide *ngFor="let q of questions | async ">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>{{q.label}}</ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content >
          <div *ngFor="let a of answers | async">
            <ion-item *ngIf="q.idWeb == a.question_id">
                <ion-label>{{a.value}}</ion-label>
                <ion-radio value="{{a.good}}"></ion-radio>
              </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the schema of data in firebase. I have to work with this only. 
Kindly suggest some solution to  improve the performance.

Comment: This might help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600154/how-can-i-speed-up-ngfor-for-a-large-array?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Common Developpement Kit provided by the Angular team.

Start by installing the CDK if you haven't :

```
npm i @angular/cdk
```

Once installed, you can follow [this guide](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) to implement an easy virtual scroll.

This will render only the items in the viewport, resulting in waaaay faster rendering.

Comment: But really, you should change your model. "This is already like that" isn't an excuse : when you have performance issues, then you optimize, no matter the cost.

Answer (score 0):

use `trackBy` to improve indexes as below. This will improve performance while re-rendering only.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of collection;trackBy: trackByFn">{{item.id}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="getItems()">Refresh items</button>
  `,
})
export class App {

  constructor() {
    this.collection = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
  }

  getItems() {
    this.collection = this.getItemsFromServer();
  }

  getItemsFromServer() {
    return [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
  }
}
```

Go through this link for more information.

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: This might work for re-rendering, but for the first rendering, it won't change anything.

Comment: updated my answer for those who are looking for re-rendering case. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Found a work around to deal with this situation. Used exapansion panel of angular material library. It provides many properties, I used opened property to call a function  and fetch  options to that particular question only whenever panel is expanded. works smooth now.

```
 <mat-accordion>

      <ion-card *ngFor="let q of questions | async">

          <mat-expansion-panel  (opened)="fetchAnswers(q)" >
              <mat-expansion-panel-header >
                  <mat-panel-description [innerHtml]="q.label">
                    </mat-panel-description>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                <ion-item *ngFor="let a of answers | async">
                  <ion-icon slot="start" name="create"></ion-icon>
                  <ion-label>
                    <p>{{a.value}}</p>
                  </ion-label>
                </ion-item>

            </mat-expansion-panel>

      </ion-card>
</mat-accordion>
```

hope it helps someone stuck in a similar situation.

note: first method was destined to fail anyways as data is supposed to reach 50,000 for answers object and 15000 for questions object in  near future.